# problems installing tensorflow

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia

My tensorflow installation doesn't work..here is the error that i get

> root@tobythomas2212:/home/tobythomas2212# python
>
> Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
>   [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> > > import tensorflow as tf
>
> I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
>
> I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
>
> I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally---
>
> I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:126] Couldn't open CUDA library libcuda.so.1. LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>
> I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:165] hostname: tobythomas2212
>
> I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] libcuda reported version is: Not found: was unable to find libcuda.so DSO loaded into this program
>
> I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:193] kernel reported version is: Permission denied: could not open driver version path for reading: /proc/driver/nvidia/version
>
> I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1065] LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>
> I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1066] failed to find libcuda.so on this system: Failed precondition: could not dlopen DSO: libcuda.so.1; dlerror: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.375.39: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally

Here the output of

`lspci | grep -i nvidia`

> *01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)*

nvcc --version

> *The program 'nvcc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>   apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit*

#### *[Note : I have already installed nvidia-375(apt-get install) driver as well as cuda-8.0 toolkit(deb installer) ]*

Also, there is no nvidia driver in */proc/driver/*

> *root@tobythomas2212:/home/tobythomas2212# cd /proc/driver/*
>   *root@tobythomas2212:/proc/driver# ls*
>
> *rtc*

#### *All previous posts dont work for me.. Need help...I'm Linux novice..*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to install the tensorflow... the error was with the secure boot option not allowing proper installation of nvidia drivers in my case...just disabled it....

following links would be useful to those having same errors..

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2882

https://gist.github.com/wangruohui/df039f0dc434d6486f5d4d098aa52d07